# Ditto clipboard manager for multiple copy and paste

Tags: clipboard, ditto

I'm using Ditto to copy+paste a huge form into another software and it comes handy to paste the last 10 data entries. However, I would like to know if it is possible to paste all the entries in the clipboard history one by one, moving to next record automatically, using a hotkey combination for example? I have tried so far to paste the 10th record in the list and moving it to the top using CRTL+Num 0 and it works for the first 10 but then it repeats itself.

I hope this make sense to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Show the Quick paste popup with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>
2. Select all items with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+“click” or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> keys
3. Paste everything <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will paste whatever the lines on your clipboard to on Notepad or Word.

Comment: to select all clips use `Ctrl+A` and enter instead of shift+click

Comment: Note: this doesn't work with images. Only the first image will be pasted. Any workarounds?
https://sourceforge.net/p/ditto-cp/discussion/287511/thread/5538f4a78d/?limit=50

Comment: workaround, 
For text, use ditto to merge multiple paste. 
For images, use shareX a screenshot tool to save screengrabs in a folder, go to explorer select all the image files, and copy to word document.